# Assigning an AWS Elastic IP to an EC2 Instance in Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, elastic-ip

Is there a way to assign an elastic ip to a ec2 instance that was just made using cloud formation scripts in amazon aws? I'm not able to find any simple examples of how to "get an elastic ip" by it's tag, or any api references about whether or not this is even possible. I need to first get the elastic ip by it's tag, and then assign it to an existing instance in lambda.

Answer (score 1):

In the AWS CLI (I'm using 2.2.4) I can get EIP's by the Name tag:

```
aws ec2 describe-addresses --filters "Name=tag:Name,Values=some-tag-here"
```

My tag has the Key "Name" as part of it.

For Python/Boto3 you can run something like:

```
import boto3
client = boto3.client('ec2')
response=client.describe_addresses(...)
```

where the parameters to `describe_addresses` are defined [in these docs](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.describe_addresses).

Answer (score 0):

From [AWS::EC2::EIP - AWS CloudFormation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-eip.html):

```yaml
MyEIP:
  Type: AWS::EC2::EIP
  Properties:
    InstanceId: !Ref Logical name of an AWS::EC2::Instance resource
```

The easiest way is to include this in the same template that launched the EC2 instance. The `!Ref` can then refer to the instance elsewhere in the template. If you want to assign an Elastic IP address in a *separate* template, then you would need to provide a reference to the EC2 instance that was previously launched.